# Detect mouse event on masked image pygame

Tags: python, events, pygame, mask

I create a clicker game and I have a transparent image (that I set in Mask for Pixel Perfect Collision ) but when I also click on the transparent part, the MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event is detected.

---

Actually, my code in the Player Class is:

```
self.image = pygame.image.load(str(level) + ".png").convert_alpha()
self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(WW, HH))
```

and this, in the main loop:

```
x, y = event.pos
if my_player.image_rect.collidepoint(x, y):
    my_player.click()
```

So I would like the click event to be triggered only when I click on the colored part of the image and not on the transparent background.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to `my_player.image_rect.collidepoint(x, y)`, check also for [`Mask.get_at`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.get_at):

> get_at()
>
> *Returns nonzero if the bit at (x,y) is set.*
>   `get_at((x,y)) -> int`

Note that you have to translate the global mouse position to the position on the mask.

---

Here's a runnable example:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
class Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('cat.png').convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (300, 200))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(400, 300))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
running = True
cat = Cat()
while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pos_in_mask = pos[0] - cat.rect.x, pos[1] - cat.rect.y
    touching = cat.rect.collidepoint(*pos) and cat.mask.get_at(pos_in_mask)

    screen.fill(pygame.Color('red') if touching else pygame.Color('green'))
    screen.blit(cat.image, cat.rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

[image]

---

Also, `self.image_rect` should be named `self.rect` by convention. It's not absolutly necessary; but it's still a good idea and enables you to work with pygame's `Sprite` class (not shown in the example).